# Azure VMSS needs access to key vault

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-virtual-machine, azure-keyvault, terraform-provider-azure

An Azure virtual machine scale set needs to use secrets from a pre-existing Azure key vault.

Terraform is the tool being used to create the Azure virtual machine scale set.

What specific terraform code must be used in order to configure the virtual machines in the virtual machine scale set to be able to automatically retrieve secrets from a named key vault which exists before the virtual machine scale set is created?

The terraform [azurerm_linux_virtual_machine_scale_set resource](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/linux_virtual_machine_scale_set) has a `secrets` block option that can receive a `key_vault_id`, but we have not been able to find examples.

What we need is for bash scripts running within the virtual machine scale set to be able to retrieve secrets from the pre-existing key vault.  Specifically the `cloud-init` startup script.

So far, we have been using the CLI to make requests to the key vault in the cloud-init script, but we are getting access denied errors.

The answer to this question should include 1. terraform code for creating the virtual machine scale set, and 2. simple code to retrieve a secret from that key vault that can be added to a bash script running in the virtual machine scale set, such as the cloud-init script.

Does the VMSS need to run as some sort of identity to make this happen?

Comment: Indeed, I think you would need a managed identity for the vm scale set to relaize this. You are mentioning a _pre-existing_ key-vault. I assume it would be necessary to import this into the terraform state in order to grant access to the managed identity.

Comment: @stdtom We imagine using the id of the pre-existing key vault as a parameter. The Key vault has a different life cycle than the vm scale set, so the key vault and the vm scale set each must managed by DIFFERENT terraform state. The key vault life cycle is OUTSIDE THE SCOPE OF THIS OP. Here, we are asking for narrowly scoped scale set definition code along with whatever 2 or 3 lines of code might go in the `cloud-init` bash script to pull secrets into a vm from the pre-existing key vault. ... If a managed identity is needed, then we would need the managed identity's terraform definition as well

Comment: Copy that. I assume you are already managing a key vault access policy in the state which also manages the key vault. So when you create a new managed identity together with the vmss, you need to authorize this identity as well to access the key vault. I can imagine that this will have to happen in the other state as well to avoid conflicts.

Comment: @stdtom The life cycle of the KeyVault is OUTSIDE SCOPE OF THIS OP. If the terraform that creates that pre-existing key vault needs to also create the managed identity that the subsequently created VM scale set needs to use in order to access the key vault, then it would be sufficient to 1. show the simple block that creates the managed identity, then 2. show how the ID for that then pre-existing managed identity can be fed into the the to-be-created vm scale set as an input variable., and 3. show the perhaps 3 lines in cloud-init which will pull secrets into a vm in the resulting scale set